# How to remove a textview and an edittext once I clicked a button?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Since I have ann add button where i can add a text view and an edit text. Now my problem is I want to ask how to remove a textview and an edittext once I click a button? My button name to remove a textview and edittext is the "Button removeStaff"

Here is my code:

_12_EventAssign.java

```
public class _12_EventAssign extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout linearL;
View lineview;

Button addStaff;
Button removeStaff;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity__12__event_assign);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Event: Information");

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    linearL = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.add_staff);
    lineview = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    removeStaff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaremovetaff);
    removeStaff.setEnabled(false);


    addStaff = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnaddstaff);
    addStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            removeStaff.setEnabled(true);

             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dpToPx(300), dpToPx(40));

            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            EditText ed = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

            params.setMargins(55, 25, 0, 0);
            tv.setText("Department");
            tv.setTextSize(25);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            linearL.addView(tv, params);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);


            params1.setMargins(dpToPx(35), dpToPx(7), 0, 0);


       ed.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
            linearL.addView(ed, params1);
            ed.setLayoutParams(params1);

        }
    });

}

public static int dpToPx(int dp)
{
    return (int) (dp * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
}
```

I hope you could help me. Thank you!

Comment: you want when click in button remove edittext ed and textview tv?

Comment: yes. how will i do that?

Answer (score 0):

So to do that you **only** need to do this:

```
removeStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   tv.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                   ed.setVisibility(View.Gone);
            }
});
```

This code **remove** the tv and the ed from layout.

Answer (score 0):

You have local references to your textview, and edittext. (tv, ed)

you can pull them as fields of the class. (put them below Button addStaff)

```
Button addStaff;
Button removeStaff;
TextView tv;
EditText ed;
```

then in your onClick listener, set them using the class field. rather than a local TextView tv = ...

```
tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
```

create your onClickListener for removeStaff

```
removeStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        linearL.removeView(tv);
        linearL.removeView(ed);
    }
}
```

Or, if you can just remove everything from the linear layout, you can simplly call removeAllViews()

```
removeStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        linearL.removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to manage visibilies of  textview and editText as on Button**

removeStaff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View view) { tv.setVisibility(View.Gone); ed.setVisibility(View.Gone); } });